# How to solve fatal header error in VS code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, header, fatal-error

Unable to run programs which include graphics header for C in Visual Studio
I have tried adding graphics header to include folder in mingw as I've been using gnu compiler but failed and unable to find any forums related to this
Please help me, anyone,

Gotten this message:

[image: pls help in solving this error]

please help in solving this error

Comment: It seems you are using a header for C++. Also [please do not post images of what can be posted as text because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: is your c file `graphics.c` and you also have a file `graphics.h` inyour loacal directory? Why does the compiler have `Graphics.c` as the filenname (Capital **G**)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It will work on few compilers only.
`Libsdl` is better for drawing because it is still stable.

[Here:](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/50570627.html)

> graphics.h is a 20 years old header that used to exist in borland
> version of Turbo C.

Answer (score 0):

this is becuase mingw does not have graphics.h file and its libraries installed in it. During the installation of mingw you probably have chosen the basic install of gcc means you does not have the complete setup of mingw in your system, now in order to fix this issue you have to download the header file and its associated libraries manually.

You can download them from here [Download WinBGIm](https://rushabhthathi.wordpress.com/2011/01/22/getting-graphics-h-to-work-on-mingw32-gnu-c-compiler/)

You have to download the WinBGIm and then you have to extract the files from there and then you have to put the graphics.h header file in your include directory and the associated libraries in the lib directory then you will be free from this error.

I forgot to mention that you will also have to download the sstream header file manually.